# Why is this simple program giving a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

I have written a simple C++ program. The idea is, once it sees a non-alphabetic character, then till the time it see a new word (a blank) or the string ends, it keeps on incrementing the iterator.

This generates Segmentation fault, no idea why :( 
Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 string str("Hello yuio");
 string::iterator it=str.begin();

 while(it!=str.end())
 {
  cout << *it << endl;

  if(isalpha(*it)==0){
   cout << *it << ":Is not an alphabet\n";

   while((*it!=' ')||(it!=str.end()))
   {
     cout << *it << endl;
     it++;
   }
  }

if(it!=str.end()){it++;}
  } // while loop ends
}  // End of main
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
while((*it!=' ')||(it!=str.end()))
```

`*it` is evaluated before checking if `it` itself is ok to use. Change to:

```
while((it!=str.end())&&(*it!=' '))
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Will be shortly accepting your answer after the system allowed 3 mins gap.

Comment: @AssafLevy While you solution fixes the issue, the explaination can be misleading. This will work fine as far both condition is tested before entering the loop. Though it is preferable to check the end condition first but I guess this will not affect in any way the functioning of the loop in the given code, if it is not the case.This is because I guess the iterator implementation must be dereferencing current character location and checking for the '\0' for asserting the end of file. So even if it is checked after the check for blank character, it will not make any difference.

Answer (score 5):

```
while((*it!=' ')||(it!=str.end()))
```

The line above contains two errors.

1. The condition says that the loop shall go on while the current character is not a space **OR** end of string is not reached yet. I.e., even when the end is reached but current char is not a space, the loop will proceed.
2. Once you fixed this error (by replacing `||` with `&&`), you still try to dereference the end iterator (because the check for space comes **before** the check for end of string), which is not allowed. You have to switch the order of conditions:

   `while((it!=str.end()) && (*it!=' '))`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
while((*it!=' ')||(it!=str.end()))
```

When you reach the end of the string, the first part of the condition is true and so you continue looping and incrementing the iterator.
You need to replace with `&&`:

```
while((*it!=' ')&&(it!=str.end()))
```

Comment: and switch them round so the end condition is evaluated first